# gulp, записать дату компиляции файла в сам файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

как записать дату сборки файлов во время компиляции с помощью gulp в начало (например) файла html

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите  вот эти плагины.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header-comment

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header